# Build webpack entries without dependency - Next.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I wanted to add custom entries to Next.js Webpack config to run them directly with `chrome.runtime.executeScript` for my browser extension. previously in CRA I could just add entries and remove `splitChunks` and `runtimeChunk` optimizations and it'd run without a problem but now in Next.js, Webpack builds them as a `webpackChunk` and they depend on `main.js` and I can't run them using `chrome.runtime.executeScript`.

Here's my webpack config in `next.config.js`:

```
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });

    if (config.target === "web" && config.mode === "production") {
      config.optimization.splitChunks = {
        cacheGroups: {
          default: false,
        },
      };
      config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;

      config.output = {
        ...config.output,
        filename: "static/chunks/[name].js",
      };


      // Setting entries and return config
      return Object.assign({}, config, {
        entry: () => {
          return config.entry().then((entry) => {
            const newEntry = {
              ...entry,
              background: "./src/browser-scripts/background.ts",
              getMetas: "./src/browser-scripts/getMetas.ts",
            };
            return newEntry;
          });
        },
      });
    }

    return config;
  }
```

Comment: how did you solve this problem?